# multinomial proportion confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, proportion, multinomial-distribution, binary-data

Is there any difference between the multinomial confidence interval for proportions and the binomial confidence interval for proportions, or do I just compute pj for j binary variables in the same equation as the binomial CI?

Mostly, I want to use this to find a sample size for .99 confidence and a half-width of .005.

Any insights into CIs for multinomial distributions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For each individual component, yes, same as Binomial (just merge all of the other components).  So that lets you make single-component statements like "with 90% confidence $1.234<\mu_5<6.789$", for example.

If you want to make multi-component statements like "with 90% confidence $\ 0.111<\mu_2<0.333\ $ *and* $\ 0.444<\mu_5<0.666$" then I would guess it's going to get complicated, as you'd be dealing with multidimensional confidence regions, not confidence intervals.

Comment: Interesting, thanks ... what is the point of multinomial sampling if I can't easily use it to place a confidence interval around each p-hat? Can you suggest anything that might help me understand how to create a CI that encompasses all components? - Ultimately, I want to find the equation so I can manipulate the half-width by changing n.

Comment: I'm no expert, sorry.  There's a mildly-terrifying paper by Sison and Glaz, "Simultaneous Confidence Intervals and Sample Size Determination for Multinomial Proportions", if you're feeling brave (I'm not ...), or more pragmatically you could try the *MultinomialCI* package for R.

Comment: The point is that the outcome is multivariate i.e. if your multinomial has $n$ categories then you get random outcomes $X_i, i=1 \dots n$ that are **dependent**.  The method I know is the one referred to by @Creosote in his comment supra.